# Getting Bot Id From Received Message In Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Let's assume that **multiple Telegram Bots** are using the **same webhook url**, Is there a way to find out which bot received the Message? the Message has **From** or **Chat** which determines the sender of Message but there is no **To** field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem for bot creators, it's usually resolved by adding a parameter with the bot token when setting the webhook.

For instance, instead of using `https://example.com/telegram` as webhook url, you can use `https://example.com/telegram?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` then read the bot token in your program logic.